# Prove that if sets $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $|A\times B| = |A|\cdot|B|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if sets $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $|A\times B| = |A|\cdot|B|$.

I started to show that if $B$ is a singleton $\{b\}$, then 
$|A\times B| = |A\times \{b\}|=|A|.$ Then, if $B = \{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so 
$A\times B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} (A\times \{b_i\})$.

My question is what should I do next? I though about showing that 
$A = \{a_1, a_2,\dots, a_m\}$, but I do not know how to "connect" it with $|A\times B|$ and then with $|A|\cdot|B|$, to get the final result.

Comment: You're essentially done (apart form the typoe: $A\times B = \cup_{i=1}^n (A \times \{b_i\})$, not $|A\times B$: that's just a number): your union is disjoint, so $|A\times B| = \sum_{i=1}^n|A \times \{b_i\} = \sum_{i=1}^n|A| = n|A| = |B|\cdot|A| = |A|\cdot|B|$.

Comment: So is the part $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m\}$ unnecessary?

Comment: Did you prove that the cardinality of a finite fisjoint union is the sum of the cardinalities?

Comment: No, I did not prove it.

Comment: To answer your question in the comments, it is necessary to include that to help show that the cardinality of $A$ is $m$ and the cardinality of $A \times B$ is the cardinality of $A$ added up $n$ times. And as for the proof of cardinality of finite disjoint union, [this link](https://planetmath.org/cardinalityofdisjointunionoffinitesets) will be of some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

Show first that if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, then the size of their union is $\lvert X \rvert + \lvert Y \rvert$. Use this fact to prove your assertion by using **induction** on the **size** of $B$:

Firstly, we have your (very useful!) result here:

$$A \times B = \bigcup_{i=1}^n ( A \times \{b_i\})$$

The base case where the size of $\lvert B \rvert$ is $1$ is proven already, as you've shown in your post. Suppose the size of $\lvert B \rvert$ is $n$. Then, by using your useful result and the inductive hypothesis:

$$ \lvert A \times B \rvert = \lvert \bigcup_{i=1}^n(A \times \{b_i\}) \rvert = \lvert \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}(A\times \{b_i\})\cup(A \times \{b_n\}) \rvert = $$

$$\lvert A \rvert (n-1) + \lvert A \rvert = \lvert A \rvert n = \lvert A \rvert \cdot \lvert B \rvert$$

where we used the fact that the size of a disjoint union is the sum of their sizes.